# Using dplyr's summarise on single column, but with multiple parameter values

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

Apologize for the not-so-clear title (could use help) - hopefully the example below will clarify many things. I have the following dataframe of basketball shot results (1 row == 1 basketball shot):

```
> dput(zed)
structure(list(shooterTeamAlias = c("DUKE", "DUKE", "BC", "DUKE", 
"DUKE", "DUKE", "DUKE", "DUKE", "DUKE", "BC", "BC", "BC", "DUKE", 
"BC", "BC", "DUKE", "DUKE", "DUKE", "BC", "DUKE"), distanceCategory = c("sht2", 
"sht2", "sht3", "atr2", "mid2", "sht2", "lng3", "sht3", "atr2", 
"sht3", "sht3", "sht2", "mid2", "sht3", "sht3", "sht3", "atr2", 
"atr2", "sht2", "mid2"), eventType = c("twopointmiss", "twopointmade", 
"threepointmade", "twopointmade", "twopointmiss", "twopointmade", 
"threepointmiss", "threepointmiss", "twopointmade", "threepointmiss", 
"threepointmade", "twopointmiss", "twopointmade", "threepointmiss", 
"threepointmade", "threepointmiss", "twopointmade", "twopointmade", 
"twopointmade", "twopointmade")), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

> zed
   shooterTeamAlias distanceCategory      eventType
1              DUKE             sht2   twopointmiss
2              DUKE             sht2   twopointmade
3                BC             sht3 threepointmade
4              DUKE             atr2   twopointmade
5              DUKE             mid2   twopointmiss
6              DUKE             sht2   twopointmade
7              DUKE             lng3 threepointmiss
8              DUKE             sht3 threepointmiss
9              DUKE             atr2   twopointmade
10               BC             sht3 threepointmiss
11               BC             sht3 threepointmade
12               BC             sht2   twopointmiss
13             DUKE             mid2   twopointmade
14               BC             sht3 threepointmiss
15               BC             sht3 threepointmade
16             DUKE             sht3 threepointmiss
17             DUKE             atr2   twopointmade
18             DUKE             atr2   twopointmade
19               BC             sht2   twopointmade
20             DUKE             mid2   twopointmade
```

This dataframe is currently in a tidy-ish format, and I need to group_by team and then fatten it big time. The full data has 6 distanceCategories `atr2, sht2, mid2, lng2, sht3, lng3` (example above has 5 only), as well as 2 categories that are a function of the other 6: `all2` is `atr2, sht2, lng2, mid2` and `all3` is `sht3, lng3`. For each of these 8 categories then, I would like a column for makes, attempts, pct, and attempt frequency. I use the `eventType` column to determine if a shot was made.  I am currently doing so with the following

```
fat.data <- {zed %>%
    dplyr::group_by(shooterTeamAlias) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(

      shotsCount = n(),
      # Shooting By Distance Stats
      atr2Made = sum(distanceCategory == "atr2" & eventType == "twopointmade"),
      atr2Att = sum(distanceCategory == "atr2" & eventType %in% c("twopointmiss", "twopointmade")),
      atr2AttFreq = atr2Att / shotsCount,
      atr2Pct = ifelse(atr2Att > 0, atr2Made / atr2Att, 0),

      sht2Made = sum(distanceCategory == "sht2" & eventType == "twopointmade"),
      sht2Att = sum(distanceCategory == "sht2" & eventType %in% c("twopointmiss", "twopointmade")),
      sht2AttFreq = sht2Att / shotsCount, 
      sht2Pct = ifelse(sht2Att > 0, sht2Made / sht2Att, 0),

      mid2Made = sum(distanceCategory == "mid2" & eventType == "twopointmade"),
      mid2Att = sum(distanceCategory == "mid2" & eventType %in% c("twopointmiss", "twopointmade")),
      mid2AttFreq = mid2Att / shotsCount,
      mid2Pct = ifelse(mid2Att > 0, mid2Made / mid2Att, 0),

      lng2Made = sum(distanceCategory == "lng2" & eventType == "twopointmade"),
      lng2Att = sum(distanceCategory == "lng2" & eventType %in% c("twopointmiss", "twopointmade")),
      lng2AttFreq = lng2Att / shotsCount,
      lng2Pct = ifelse(lng2Att > 0, lng2Made / lng2Att, 0),

      all2Made = sum(atr2Made, sht2Made, mid2Made, lng2Made),
      all2Att = sum(atr2Att, sht2Att, mid2Att, lng2Att),
      all2AttFreq = all2Att / shotsCount,
      all2Pct = ifelse(all2Att > 0, all2Made / all2Att, 0),

      sht3Made = sum(distanceCategory == "sht3" & eventType == "threepointmade"),
      sht3Att = sum(distanceCategory == "sht3" & eventType %in% c("threepointmiss", "threepointmade")),
      sht3AttFreq = sht3Att / shotsCount,
      sht3Pct = ifelse(sht3Att > 0, sht3Made / sht3Att, 0),

      lng3Made = sum(distanceCategory == "lng3" & eventType == "threepointmade"),
      lng3Att = sum(distanceCategory == "lng3" & eventType %in% c("threepointmiss", "threepointmade")),
      lng3AttFreq = lng3Att / shotsCount,
      lng3Pct = ifelse(lng3Att > 0, lng3Made / lng3Att, 0),

      all3Made = sum(sht3Made, lng3Made),
      all3Att = sum(sht3Att, lng3Att),
      all3AttFreq = all3Att / shotsCount,
      all3Pct = ifelse(all3Att > 0, all3Made / all3Att, 0))}
```

...for the 6 categories that appear in the data (all but `all2` and `all3`), their 4 columns are all computed in the same manner. As you'll see for `all2` and `all3`, the calculations are a bit different.

Not worrying for the time being about the `all2` and `all3` categories, is there a better way to compute the makes, attempts, pct, and attempt frequencies for the 6 categories in the data? For the 8 categories * 4 column-types == 32 columns here, it's not so bad, but I have another, similar instance where I have 21 categories * 4 column-types, and I have to do this multiple times in my code.

Not sure if `dplyr::group_by dplyr::summarise` is my best option (obv it's what im using currently), or if there's a better way to go about this. Improving this code / potentially speeding it up for my project is pivotally important, and any help is appreciated / i'll try to remember to bounty this post even if answered in the next 2 days.

**Edit !!! :** I've just realized that grouping by the distanceCategory first, computing the 4 stats for each distanceCategory, and then re-structuring **that** dataframe into this fat format may be easier... it is something I'm working on computing currently. Something along these lines:

```
zed %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(shooterTeamAlias, distanceCategory) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    attempts = ...,
    makes = ...,
    pct = ...,
    attfreq = ...
  ) %>%
  tidyr::spread(...)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it could be made simpler by grouping by distanceCategory and then applying the same logic to each:

```
library(tidyverse)
zed %>%
  group_by(shooterTeamAlias, distanceCategory) %>%
  summarize(att = n(),   # n() counts how many rows in this group
            made = sum(eventType %>% str_detect("made"))
            pct = if_else(att > 0, made / att, 0)) %>%
  mutate(freq = att / sum(att))

# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   shooterTeamAlias [2]
  shooterTeamAlias distanceCategory   att  made   pct   freq
  <chr>            <chr>            <int> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 BC               sht2                 2     1 0.5   0.286 
2 BC               sht3                 5     3 0.6   0.714 
3 DUKE             atr2                 4     4 1     0.308 
4 DUKE             lng3                 1     0 0     0.0769
5 DUKE             mid2                 3     2 0.667 0.231 
6 DUKE             sht2                 3     2 0.667 0.231 
7 DUKE             sht3                 2     0 0     0.154
```

If you want that in wide format, you could first gather the calculations above, unite the distance with the stat, and then spread by that:

```
[same code as above] %>%
  gather(stat, value, -distanceCategory, -shooterTeamAlias) %>%
  unite(stat, distanceCategory, stat) %>%
  spread(stat, value)

# A tibble: 2 x 21
# Groups:   shooterTeamAlias [2]
  shooterTeamAlias atr2_att atr2_freq atr2_made atr2_pct lng3_att lng3_freq lng3_made lng3_pct mid2_att mid2_freq mid2_made mid2_pct sht2_att sht2_freq sht2_made sht2_pct sht3_att sht3_freq sht3_made sht3_pct
  <chr>               <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 BC                     NA    NA            NA       NA       NA   NA             NA       NA       NA    NA            NA   NA            2     0.286         1    0.5          5     0.714         3      0.6
2 DUKE                    4     0.308         4        1        1    0.0769         0        0        3     0.231         2    0.667        3     0.231         2    0.667        2     0.154         0      0
```